# I keep getting this error: Error in check_factor(.f) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, dplyr

I keep getting this error:

> Error in check_factor(.f) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

```r
select(c(10:25)) %>%
  mutate_all(factor,
             fct_recode(
               "Strongly Satisfied" = "1",
               "Satisfied" = "2",
               "Neither" = "3",
               "Dissatisfied" = "4",
               "Strongly Dissatisfied" = "5"
             ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite clearly a duplicate that has already been answered elsewhere. However, I would like to try to answer your question again here, as I think your problem is not so much with the fct_recode function, but rather with the way you are trying to use mutate_all.

The error means that you do not specify a variable to be changed with fct_recode. Here is a working example of the input expected by fct_recode:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x_1 = factor(c(1,2,3,4,5)))
df %>% mutate(x_1 = fct_recode(x_1, 
                    "Strongly Satisfied" = "1",
                    "Satisfied" = "2",
                    "Neither" = "3",
                    "Dissatisfied" = "4",
                    "Strongly Dissatisfied" = "5"))
```

As you can see, a variable must be specified (in the example x_1) to avoid the error.

Now to the use of mutate_all(): You seem to want to change different columns with the use of fct_recode within mutate_all. The lifecycle of mutate_all (and the other mutate_... functions) is superseded and has been replaced by mutate(across()). A working example using across would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x_1 = c(2, 3,4,5,4,3),
             x_2 = c(NA,4,2,3,4,1),
             x_3 = c(NA,2,3,1,3,NA)) 

df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = (x_1:x_3),
                .fns = ~factor(., 
                               levels = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                               labels = c("Strongly Satisfied",
                                          "Satisfied",
                                          "Neither",
                                          "Dissatisfied",
                                          "Strongly Dissatisfied"))))
```

In this example I have refrained from using fct_recode(). Since you want to use the factor() function in your code beforehand, I assume that the variables still have to be transformed into factor variables, which is achieved with this code in one step.